# jsp java: my tag files don't replace parameters

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags

script.tag:

```
<%@ attribute name="file" required="true"%>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/${file}"></script>
```

my.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%> 
<%@ taglib tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" prefix="x"%>
<x:script file="register.js"/>
```

however, the `${file}` param does not get replaced and stays literally `${file}`

**Help!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving to tomcat 6 fixed this.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding pageScope when you use the attribute in the tag?  Like this:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/${pageScope.file}"></script>`